# JS input type="text" value умножить на постоянное значение (цена)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как умножить значение из input value="text" на постоянное значение из div.constanta

Например :

```html
<input type="text" class="sizeinput" min="1" value="1">

<div class="constanta">2500</div>

<div class="rezultVal">
```

Если меняем значение в input на 5 результат меняется на умножение: 12500

Как это сделать?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery

```
const result = $('.rezultVal');
const constanta = parseFloat($('.constanta').html());
$('.sizeinput').input(e => {
    result.html(constanta * parseFloat(e.target.value));
});
```

Или на чистом JavaScript

```
const result = document.querySelector('.rezultVal');
const constanta = parseFloat(document.querySelector('.constanta').innerHTML);
document.querySelector('.sizeinput').addEventListener('input', e => {
    result.innerHTML = constanta * parseFloat(e.target.value);
});
```

Comment: но почему значение сразу не показывается, а только после нажатие